# Italicizing text in urwid

Tags: python, urwid

I am using urwid to design a curses ui. I can use display attributes to show text bold, underlined, or standout. Is it possible to use italics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

In theory, yes.

**In practice: not yet.**

### Long answer

Basically, curses uses the so-called ‘ANSI escape sequences’ from ECMA-48 to do cursor movement, colours or anything that is not pure, linear text output.  (It really is more convoluted than that, cf. terminfo, but that’s what it eventually boils down to.)

Colours, bold text and so on are specified as part of the SGR (‘Select Graphic Rendition’) command: `CSI $n m` (with `CSI` being the ‘Control Sequence Introducer’ `^[[`, that is `ESC`+`[`).  Amongst a baffling array of stuff bordering on the bizarre (There’s even support for *blackletter*!  On the console!), there *is* a control sequence for italic text: `^[[3m` to enable, `^[[23m` to disable.

Wikipedia has a [list of SGR commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics).  However, most of the more… esoteric sequences are ‘hardly ever supported’.  Bold and standout are almost universally supported, underlined is common.  While italic seems to be gaining traction, many (?) terminal emulators still don’t support it—which might be a concern if your program needs to function in a heterogeneous environment.  And better not place any bets on blackletter support coming anytime soon.

Right now, xterm, urxvt, and st do support it; PuTTy does not.

You can try out for yourself if your terminal would support it.  You have to use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to get a ‘real’ escape character instead of `^[`, which is merely a notational shorthand.

```
print 'plain text ^[[3m italic text ^[[0m plain text'
```

[ncurses already seems to support italic text.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107632/ncurses-support-for-italics)  **Urwid, however, does not yet** (as of version 1.3.0).  I’ve looked through the source code (the interesting bits are `display_common.py`, `curses_display.py` and `raw_display.py`).  I guess it shouldn’t be too difficult to patch in support for italic text, but as an Urwid beginner myself that’s out of reach for me right now.

Comment: That escape sequence works in xterm, urxvt, and st, so it looks like it is more widely supported than you say.

Comment: Thanks for poiting out!  Seems that I managed to try it with precisely those that don’t. ^^  I’ll try to update my answer as soon as I have time to put my hand on some xterm.